# Auto-replace special characters in input / bash?

Tags: bash

Let's say, I have the following in my .bashrc

```
test1() { echo $@; }
```

and I want the following to run in my terminal

```
test1 1 and (2 and 3)
```

which should output

```
1 and (2 and 3)
```

But this just gives me a syntax error, because of the brackets. Is there any way to fix this, besides using

```
test1 "1 and (2 and 3)"
```

? Maybe with first replacing all specials chars (like the brackets)?

Comment: You *have* to protect special characters *somehow*. You would not expect `test1 $HOME` to magically avoid expanding the variable (I hope)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the special meaning of the brackets using backslash:

```
test1 1 and \(2 and 3\)
```

Or quote the bracketed text:

```
test1 1 and "(2 and 3)"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
test1 "1 and (2 and 3)"
```

... will give you the expected output.

Reference:
http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/abs-guide.html  -> "Subshells"

What is inside unquoted parantheses in bash, is launched as a subshell, in parallell with the currently running shell.

Answer (score 0):

It’s not entirely clear what your objective is. 
Given that, this might be what you want:

```
(shell prompt)$ test1() { printf "data? "; read -r tdata && printf "%s\n" "$tdata"; }
(shell prompt)$ 
(shell prompt)$ test1
data? 1 and (2 and 3)           (You type the part in bold.)
1 and (2 and 3)                 (Your test1 function repeats your input back to you.)
(shell prompt)$
```